# Time difference calculation in android

Tags: java, android

I am calculating time difference and subtracting break from difference time

I am unable subtract break time from time difference.

```
    long hoursDifference,mindifference;
            d1 = df.parse(strattime);
            d2 = df.parse(endtime);
            d3= df1.parse(textbreaktime);

     hoursDifference = (long) (d3.getTime()-((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()))
            / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24);
     mindifference = (long) ((d3.getTime()-(d2.getTime()) - d1.getTime())
            / (60 * 1000) % 60);
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the actual output you get? what type of output do you expect?

Comment: eg d1 is 2.30 d2 3.00 is 00.30 break is 0.05 then 00.25

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are two wrong brackets, correct it should look like this

```
 long hoursDifference,mindifference;
        d1 = df.parse(strattime);
        d2 = df.parse(endtime);
        d3= df1.parse(textbreaktime);

 hoursDifference = (long) (((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) - d3.getTime())
        / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24;
 mindifference = (long) (((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) - d3.getTime())
        / (60 * 1000)) % 60;
```

But much easier (and better readable) would it be if you use the Date functions like

```
Date result = new Date((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) - d3.getTime());
int hours = result.getHours();
int minutes = result.getMinutes();
```

*Edit:*
Is that what you want?
d1 = 2:00
d2 = 2:30
d3 = 0:05
result = (2:30 - 2:00) - 0:05 = 0:25

Comment: this gives difference it not subtracting break time